# Is it possible to limit satis to a single vendor?

Tags: php, satis

I want to use satis to provide dependencies of projects I am developing.
So I know I can use options: `require-dependencies`, `require-dev-dependencies` and `only-dependencies` to include dependencies of my project.
But this will add all dependencies including laravel, symfony and all the third party libraries.

Is there a way to tell Satis to include dependencies but only from a single vendor?

So if project's `composer.json` has:

```
"require": [
    "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
    "hubertnnn/foo": "^1.0",
    "hubertnnn/bar": "^2.0"
]
```

Satis should only contain `hubertnnn/foo` and `hubertnnn/bar`, but not `laravel/framework`

Comment: You can directly provide a repository from where you want to install packages: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages.md#setup